# Sort object based on financial year object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I want to sort **monthYearObj**  based on **financeYears**

```
var financeYears = 
[{"month":4,"year":2019,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":5,"year":2019,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":6,"year":2019,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":7,"year":2019,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":8,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":9,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":10,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":11,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":12,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":1,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":2,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"},
{"month":3,"year":2020,"resourceType":"Employee"}]

var monthYearObj = 
[{"monthStart":1,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":2,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":3,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":4,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":5,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":6,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":7,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":8,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":9,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":10,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":0,"yearStart":0},
{"monthStart":0,"yearStart":0}];
```

and want output as below and in place of `{"monthStart":0,"yearStart":0}` should have `{"monthStart":11,"yearStart":2020}` and `{"monthStart":12,"yearStart":2020}` respectively based on financeYears object as those two month's data is missing to be added here.

```
var finalObject = [
{"monthStart":4,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":5,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":6,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":7,"yearStart":2019},
{"monthStart":8,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":9,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":10,"yearStart":2020}
{"monthStart":11,"yearStart":2020}
{"monthStart":12,"yearStart":2020}
{"monthStart":1,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":2,"yearStart":2020},
{"monthStart":3,"yearStart":2020}];
```

Was trying sort function as like below but seems not working as expected ,

```
       monthYearObj.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.yearStart < b.yearStart ){
          return -1;
        } if (a.yearStart > b.yearStart){
            return 1;
        } 

        if (a.monthStart < b.monthStart ){
          return -1;
        } if (a.monthStart > b.monthStart){
            return 1;
        }

      });
```

So now i want to sort it based on financeYears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the value and map in order either the stored value or create a new object with the given data.

```js
var financeYears = [{ month: 4, year: 2019, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 5, year: 2019, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 6, year: 2019, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 7, year: 2019, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 8, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 9, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 10, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 11, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 12, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 1, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 2, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }, { month: 3, year: 2020, resourceType: "Employee" }],
    monthYearObj = [{ monthStart: 1, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 2, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 3, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 4, yearStart: 2019 }, { monthStart: 5, yearStart: 2019 }, { monthStart: 6, yearStart: 2019 }, { monthStart: 7, yearStart: 2019 }, { monthStart: 8, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 9, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 10, yearStart: 2020 }, { monthStart: 0, yearStart: 0 }, { monthStart: 0, yearStart: 0 }],
    order = monthYearObj .reduce((r, o, i) => {
        if (!o.monthStart) r[o.monthStart + '|' + o.yearStart] = o;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = financeYears.map(({ month, year }) => order[month + '|' + year] || { monthStart: month, yearStart: year });

monthYearObj.sort((a, b) => order[a.yearStart + '|' + a.monthStart] - order[b.yearStart + '|' + b.monthStart]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Only thing i forget to mention my question so  updating my question
Missed two month data as its 12 months  object so adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function should `return 0` at the bottom because the 2 elements are equal. Also, you're not using your financeYears object at all, you're just sorting by year and month.